# Error while installing topicmodels package in GNU/Linux

Tags: r

I am trying to install "topicmodels" package in R version 3.0.1 beta.

Following are my commands and errors so far:

COMMAND:

```
    install.packages("path/library/gsl_1.9-10.tar.gz",repos=NULL,type="source")
    install.packages("path/library/topicmodels_0.2-1.tar.gz",repos=NULL,type="source")
```

TEST FOR "gsl" installation:

```
    > library(gsl)
    > #No problem with this installation
```

But when I try to do the "topicmodels" installation I receive the following error:

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
namespace 'tm' 0.5-10 is being loaded, but >= 0.6 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'topicmodels'

* removing 'path/topicmodels'
* restoring previous 'path/library/topicmodels'
```

Comment: I edit my question and reposted it.

Comment: The error is clar :`namespace 'tm' 0.5-10 is being loaded, but >= 0.6 is required` , remove installed `tm` package  and install a new version. Maybe I am not sure but you can try with `install.packages(...,dependencies=TRUE)`

Comment: Looks like I need a new R-version because my current version is not allowing me to install tm 0.6 package.Appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a solution that worked on Ubuntu 17.10 for me: Go to http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gsl/ and download the last numbered .tar version of gsl. Extract the files. Then, in terminal, follow the four steps below:

1. `cd ~/Downloads/gsl-2.4 ## (or wherever extracted gsl directory is)
2. `./configure`
3. `make`
4. `sudo make install`

Then restart R and try to install again

`install.packages("topicmodels")`